# Create a collapsing appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter-android

Hello im want to create an collapsing appbar like this

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vSJd.png)

and when we scrolling the page up it will be like this

[after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhusN.png)

but i cant find anything about this style for collapsing appbar in flutter or making something like this

i hope someone can help